# MongoDB drivers

Tags: php, mongodb

I am writing some PHP code and using MongoDB free cloud cluster. It is my first time using MongoDB.
PHP running on EC2 Ubuntu instance where I installed MongoDB driver:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

My question is why I am able to connect to MongoDB only using this driver:
*MongoDB\Driver\Manager*?
I didn't found a way to use *MongoDB\Client* like on their site https://docs.mongodb.com/. What is a difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

There have been several PHP drivers for MongoDB over the years. Make sure the documentation/tutorials you are following match the driver you are using.